# Can't import Python package installed with Pacman on Arch Linux

Tags: python, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

Whenever I try to import a Python package that I installed via [Pacman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Pacman), I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named [packageName]
```

In the past, I have just got around this issue by installing the packages that I need via *pip*, which works fine. However, in this case, that is not an option.

Here's some stuff which might be useful to know. I'm not sure which parts of this information are relevant, but anyway:

- Running `python` tells me that my version is `Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.`
- Output of `which python` is `/home/username/miniconda3/bin/python`
- I have the line `export PATH="/home/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` in my ~/.bashrc
- Running `import sys`, `print(sys.path)` gives `['', '/home/username/miniconda3/bin', '/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.6', '/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Mako-1.0.7-py3.6.egg', '/home/username/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/username/.ipython']`

Comment: What does ``python -c import sys; print(sys.path)`` returns?

Comment: `pacman` is a package manager for linux packages. use `pip` to install python packages.

Comment: @MEE: ``pacman`` provides python packages and there is nothing wrong in installing and using them. And you can use at the same time packages installed with ``pacman`` and ``pip`` (using the ``--user`` option). On top of it, some packages are (nearly) impossible to install with ``pip`` (see PyQt4).

Comment: @MEE In archlinux t is [preferred](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/python#Package_management) to use pacman for installing python packages when available in the arch repository.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda's Python interpreter is isolated from the system.
If you install anything system-wide, your Anaconda's Python won't be able to find it.

If you want/need to use Anaconda you have two options:

- use `conda`
- use the `pip` that comes with Anaconda (which very likely is the version that you are using)

Otherwise don't use Anaconda: remove `/home/username/miniconda3/bin/python` from your `PATH` and use the system Python executable (should be something like `/usr/bin/python`). The system Python executable knows where to look for packages installed with your system package manager, e.g. `packman`)

Comment: The problem with switching to `/usr/bin/python` is that I have a number of packages, such as Pytorch, which can only be installed via conda. Is there any way I could access these after switching?

Comment: In theory might be possible, but you are asking for troubles. You should be able to trick python setting the ``PYTHONPATH`` to point to the packages that you want to use. But Anaconda ships its own libraries (.so and .a files) and they might not be compatible with the ones shipped by ``archlinux`` and there are good probability that you end up with library conflicts. Furthermore in my experience the use of ``PYTHONPATH`` causes more troubles that good